# How to configure location for Xamarin.Android package downlaod/unzipping?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I can't build any of my Xamarin Android projects in visual studio 2015 Xamarin. (Windows 10)

The problem is that one of my nuget packages Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable is causing files to be magically downloaded and unzipped into my C:\Users\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable .........

many, many more layers of directories are unzipped into this folder, and it ends up **exceeding 260 chars** which is the max size on windows. This causes build errors for all projects that include this "Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" library.

**How can I configure the folder that these files are placed into?**

I can't see which files are exceeding the length, it does not tell me. However I do believe that it is not overflowing by much and moving it closer to the root would fix this. I believe this because my co workers are not seeing this error and their windows usernames are about 10 to 15 chars shorter than mine (so the character overflow must not be a lot).

Comment: Sadly the best thing you can do is either: A) move closer to root B) change your project name to be shorter C) Cut down folder names in your project to prevent this. Not much you can really do here.

Comment: @JonDouglas The project name or folder names don't have anything to do with this path. It's the path to my user's `AppData\Local\Xamarin\...`  What do you mean move closer to the root? Move the app data folder closer to the root?...

Comment: The folder path should contain the `username` by default. Thus having a very long username could be worked around by shortening it. Otherwise you could potentially override the MSBuild properties that grab those caches with ones closer to a root. This is a Windows limitation unfortunately.

Comment: I was referring to other normal windows path limitations in my first post. I think you understand the easiest way to fix it with your domain name. In the future dotnet should have the path limitation lifted. However I'm not sure that will fix this issue. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/645

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move the files closer to the root by switching domain users to a user with a shorter username, and it caused all of the files to fit.

So, the path went from

```
C:\Users\<24 character username>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable
```

to

```
C:\Users\<8 char username>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable
```